# Why is one-armed "if" missing from Racket?

Tags: racket

In [standard Scheme](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_idx_366) it is possible to write

```
(if (> x 2)
    (set! x (- x 1)))
```

but this is not possible in Racket -- Racket's [`if`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html?q=if#%28form._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._if%29%29) always requires two arms. Why?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**Rationale**

The one-armed variant of `if` was removed from Racket to prevent bugs.

In functional code one always uses the two-armed variant of `if`.

```
(if test expr-on-true expr-on-false)
```

Forgetting the second arm `expr-on-false` would not lead to a syntax-error, but to a runtime error (the expression would return `#<void>`).

To prevent these often occurring bugs in functional code, it was decided to introduce the form `when` for the one-armed variant of `if`.

```
 (when test expr-on-true)
```

Besides preventing accidental bugs, the new form clearly indicated to a reader of code, that the code relies on side effects.

**Porting code from standard Scheme to Racket**

If you try running Scheme code in Racket and see the error message

```
if: bad syntax (must have an "else" expression)
```

you must rewrite the `if` expression to `when` or `unless`.

Simply rewrite:

```
(if test expr1)    to    (when test expr1)
```

and

```
(if (not test) expr1)   to    (unless test expr1).
```