# All: A Function Returning True if and only if All Elements of a List are True

Tags: scheme, racket

I am looking for a built-in function in Racket that will return True iff all the items in a list are true.

I tried:

```
(define (all lst)
  (when 
      (equal? lst '()) 
      #t)
  (if (not (car lst))
      #f
      (all (cdr lst))))
```

Giving error:

```
car: contract violation
  expected: pair?
  given: '()
```

A couple of testcases:

```
(all '(#t #f #t)) ; #f
(all '(#t #t #t)) ; #t
```

Could you please either fix it or point me to the built-in function?
(I [googled](https://www.google.it/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=racket%20list%20identity&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=LeNFVdCQAqLD8gf4kYDYAg#channel=fs&q=racket%20all%20function), but got no meaningful result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two kinds of lists: empty ones and pairs.

Therefore we have the following structure:

```
(define (all xs)
  (cond
    [(empty? xs) ...]
    [(pair?  xs) ...]
    [else        (error 'all "expected a list, got: " xs)]))
```

Since all elements in the empty list are true, we get:

```
(define (all xs)
  (cond
    [(empty? xs) #t]
    [(pair?  xs) ...]
    [else        (error 'all "expected a list, got: " xs)]))
```

If a list begins with a pair, then all elements of the list are true,
if both the first element of the list and the rest of the elements of the list are true:

```
(define (all xs)
  (cond
    [(empty? xs) #t]
    [(pair?  xs) (and (first xs) (all (rest xs)))]
    [else        (error 'all "expected a list, got: " xs)]))
```

Note that part of the problem in your program is the use of `when`.

The result of

```
(when #t
   'foo)
'bar
```

is `'bar`. The construct `when` is only useful if you are using side effects (such as caused by `set!` and friends).

Comment: Is `xs` a conventional name for a list?

Comment: Yes. There are more than one convention though. I use x as the name of an element of a list xs. If I have a list of lists, I call it xss.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very clear function, only I don't understand why this is not built-in...

Comment: Take a look at `andmap`.

Comment: Or use:   (for/and ([x xs]) x)

Comment: So I can  `(define (all xs)
    (andmap identity xs))` , interesting.

Comment: Yes, that's a fine solution.

Comment: It would be good to explain the actual problem with OP's code, though.  It was very close to correct, but just had the problem that it wasn't *returning* the value for the empty list case.

Answer (score 5):

You've already accepted another answer that explains a nice way to do this, but I think it's worth pointing out what was wrong in your attempt, because it was actually very close.  The problem is that true from the **when** block is completely ignored.  It doesn't cause the function to return.  So even when you have the empty list, you evaluate the **when**, and then *keep on going* into the other part where you call **car** and **cdr** with the same empty list:

```
(define (all lst)
  (when                  ;  The whole (when ...) expression
      (equal? lst '())   ;  is evaluated, and then its result
      #t)                ;  is ignored.
  (if (not (car lst))   
      #f
      (all (cdr lst))))
```

A very quick solution would be to change it to:

```
(define (all lst)
  (if (equal? lst '())  
      #t               
      (if (not (car lst))   
          #f
          (all (cdr lst)))))
```

At that point, you can simplify a little bit by using boolean operators rather than returning true and false explicitly, and clean up a little bit by using **empty?**, as noted in the other answer:

```
(define (all lst)
  (or (empty? lst)  
      (and (car lst)
           (all (cdr lst)))))
```

You were actually very close at the start.

Comment: Is `when` not returning a bug or the intended behaviour of the keyword? I though `when` was just a 'one armed' version of `if`.

Comment: (when expr1 expr2) is short for (if expr1 expr2 (void))

Comment: And if you are curious, why one-armed ifs were removed from Racket: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10863192/23567

Comment: @Caridorc `(when test condition)` is short for a one-armed version, so to speak, but an ìf` doesn't terminate the procedure either.  E.g., `(define (foo) (if #t 1 2) (if #t 3 4))` returns 3, not 1.  The first if expression, `(if #t 1 2)` evaluates to true, but then the evaluation of `foo` continues to `(if #t 3 4)`, which evaluates to `3`.  In the same way `(define (foo) (when #t 1) (if #t 3 4))`, which is like your original code, produces 3, not 1.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a builtin solution, you'll probably want to take a look at [`andmap`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._andmap%29%29), which applies a predicate over an entire list and `and`s the results together.

You could use this to implement `all` very simply.

```
(define (all lst)
  (andmap identity lst))
```

By using `identity` from `racket/function`, `all` will just use the values in the list as-is. Instead of using `identity` explicitly, you could also use `values`, which is just the identity function on single values, so it's a somewhat common idiom in Racket.

Comment: `andmap` is not available in most Scheme implementations. In addition, it does not always return `#t` but rather something that evaluates to `#t`. I'm not sure it meets the letter of the specification in the question even if it might meet the spirit.

Comment: @benrudgers Well, the question does explicitly specify Racket, and it also requests a built-in implementation if one exists, so here it is. It's also easy to convert from a truthy/falsy value to a boolean, but usually it's not necessary.

Comment: It is also tagged "scheme". Otherwise I wouldn't have worried about some poor schemer stumbling onto `andmap`  two years from now only to find it wasn't available. `Andmap`'s evaluation is a bit of a bigger issue since `(+ 1 (andmap '(#t)))` throws `exn:fail:contract` but `(+1 (andmap '(1)))` evalutes to `2`. It's a bit of a latent bug of the sort that makes for black-box-abstraction unhappiness. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

`All` is a [higher order folding function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29). Scheme refers to these as "reductions" and `reduce` is available in [SRFI-1](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-1.html)

In [Gauche](http://practical-scheme.net/gauche/man/gauche-refe_toc.html#SEC_Contents) Scheme:

```
(use srfi-1)
(define (all list-of-x)
  (reduce (lambda (x y) 
            (and x y))
          #t
          list-of-x))
```

Will return `#f` or a value that evaluates to true. For example:

```
gosh> (all '(1 2 3))
1
```

If that's OK, then we're done. Otherwise we can always get `#t` with:

```
(use srfi-1)
(define (all-2 list-of-x)
  (if (reduce (lambda (x y)
        (and x y))
          #t
          list-of-x)
      #t
      #f))
```

And then wind up with:

```
gosh> (all '(1 2 3))
#t
```