# Scheme function to return the longer of two lists or true if they are equal

Tags: racket

I'm new to scheme and working on a problem defined as follows:

Write a function named longer-list that takes two list arguments and returns the longer list of the two inputs. If the two lists are equal in length, the function returns #t, and if one of the arguments is not a list, the function should return #f. 
Note: You are not allowed to use the predefined length function; however, you can write your version of length or other helper functions that you may want to call from longer-list.

```
Sample runs:

(longer-list '(1 2 3 4) '(a b c d e)) returns (a b c d e)
(longer-list '(d e f) '(4 5 6)) returns #t (or true)
(longer-list '(g h i) 3) returns #f (or false)
```

what I have so far is:

```
;;helper function to determine the length of a list
(define (list-length lst)
  (if (null? length)
    0
    (+1 (list-length (cdr lst)))))

 ;;main function to return the longer of 2 lists or True if they are equal 
 (define (longer-list lst1 lst2)
   ;;check if both parameters are actually lists
   (and (list? lst1)
      (list? lst2)
      ;;if lst1 is the longer list return lst1
      (if(> (list-length lst1) (list-length lst2))
         lst1)
      ;;else lst2 is longer, return that 
      (else (> (list-length lst1 (list-length lst2))
         lst2))

     ;define comp as comparing list1 abbreviated by x and list2 abbreviated by y???
     (let comp ((x lst1) (y lst2))
       (cond
         ;;if both lists are null return true
         ((and (null? x) (null? y)) #t)
         ;;not sure what this means?
         ((null? x) lst2)
         ;;not sure what this means? 
         ((null? y) lst1)
         ;;else invoke comp after the first element of each list is removed???
         (else (comp (cdr x) (cdr y)))))))
```

Currently I'm getting the following error:

"if: missing an "else" expression in: (if (> (list-length lst1) (list-length lst2)) lst1)"

My question is what is causing this error.  Additionally, I found some of this code online and need to make sure I fully understand it so if someone could check my comments to see if they make sense, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if statements are in the form (if (evaluation expression) (true expression) (false expression))

Comment: In your previous question you also had difficulties with `if`'s syntax, please take some time to read the docs. Also, notice that `else` can only be used as part of a `cond`expression, not in an `if` expression.

Comment: I changed the tag from "Scheme" to "Racket". One-armed if is legal in Scheme, so the above error can't occur in Scheme. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863192/why-is-one-armed-if-missing-from-racket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is fine, of course. The errors in the original code were caused by an incorrect use of `if`, please read the [docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html). The code you found online is simply traversing both lists at the same time, and if one ends before the other it's because it's shorter.

A better option would be to just use the `list-length` procedure you already have - this has the advantage of not having to write an explicit loop. In Scheme we try to reuse existing procedures instead of writing new ones; for example:

```
(define (list-length lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      0
      (+ 1 (list-length (cdr lst)))))

(define (longer-list lst1 lst2)
  (if (or (not (list? lst1)) (not (list? lst2)))
      #f
      (let ((len1 (list-length lst1))
            (len2 (list-length lst2)))
        (cond ((> len1 len2) lst1)
              ((< len1 len2) lst2)
              (else #t)))))
```

It works as expected, and is easier to understand!

```
(longer-list '(1 2 3 4) '(a b c d e))
=> '(a b c d e)
(longer-list '(d e f) '(4 5 6))
=> #t
(longer-list '(g h i) 3)
=> #f
```

Answer (score 1):

this appears to have worked

```
#lang racket

(define (longer-list lst1 lst2)
  (and (list? lst1)
     (list? lst2)

     (let comp ((x lst1) (y lst2))
       (cond
         ((and (null? x) (null? y)) #t)
         ((null? x) lst2)
         ((null? y) lst1)
         (else (comp (cdr x) (cdr y)))))))
```